# Merging two dataframes using only columns from one dataframe and ignoring others in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes, I've been reading the different posts but I couldn't find a way to obtain my desired output.

```
dfA:
Name Surname C
Ja Men T
Ale Bu T
Ge Men 

dfB:

Name Surname C Ex
Ge Men T hello
Je Di T hello
```

Desired output:

```
Merge:
Name Surname C
Ja Men T
Ale Bu T
Ge Men T
Je Di T
```

That is, fill the columns in dfA with the available columns in dfB and ignore the columns from dfB that are not present in dfA.

I tried:

```
merge(dfA,dfB, by=c("Name", "Surname", "Caracter"), all.x = T)
```

And other combinations of the merge. I tried using dplyr but couldn't get a satisfactory results.

Any help would be aprreciated.

Thanks in advance

Data:

```
dfA <- data.frame(
  name=c("Ja", "Ale", "Ge"),
  surname=c("Men", "Bu", "Men"), 
  C= c("T", "T", NA))

dfB <- data.frame(
  name=c("Ge", "Je"),
  surname=c("Men","Di"), 
  C= c("T","T"),
  X = c("hello","hello"))
```

Using dput():

```
# based on dput(dfA)
dfA <- structure(list(name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Ale", 
"Ge", "Ja"), class = "factor"), surname = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Bu", "Men"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(1L, 
1L, NA), .Label = "T", class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", 
"surname", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

# based on dput(dfB)
dfB <- structure(list(name = structure(1L, .Label = "Ge", class = "factor"), 
    surname = structure(1L, .Label = "Men", class = "factor"), 
    C = "T", X = structure(1L, .Label = "hello", class = "factor")), 
    .Names = c("name", "surname", "C", "X"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducable example.

Comment: dput on both dataframes on updated answer

Comment: I changed the T to string "T". But I just want the value to be replaced, this is a toy example. thanks again.

Comment: I have changed the TRUE to "T" in your `dput` output.

Comment: Try `full_join(dfB, dfA) %>% select(-X) %>% group_by(name, surname) %>% na.omit()`

Comment: Khashaa, full_join worked! but in my real dataframe I have more variables in my dataframeA and also more variables in dataframeB. Is it possible to join both regardless of the number of variables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is as in the output shown at the end of the question, we perform a left join of `dfA` with `dfB` .  Note that `coalese` returns its first non-null argument -- `NA`s are regarded as SQL nulls:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select A.Name, A.Surname, coalesce(A.C, B.C) C
       from dfA A left join dfB B on A.Name = B.Name and A.Surname = B.Surname")
```

giving:

```
  name surname C
1   Ja     Men T
2  Ale      Bu T
3   Ge     Men T
```

Comment: I am working on OSX and there is a problem with Quartz I'll check the answer after resolving this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what the function is doing? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having problems installing the package and getting and error. Maybe another way using another package... sorry for this

Comment: Are you using an old version of R?  Maybe you need to get a newer one.

Comment: I updated the version and it worked!! So in order to make this reproducible to other variables, do I only need to add coalesce(A.variablename, B.variablename) variablename , to the first part of the function?

Comment: Is it also possible to add a new row from dfB if it wasn't present in dfA?

Comment: Yes, add a `coalesce(...) new_name` for each column that is to be obtained from `dfA` or if null from `dfB`.   To include rows from each data frame that do not exist in the other use `select ... from dfA left join dfB on ... union select ... from dfB left join dfA on ...` .

Comment: Thanks, I've never used a sql package. I made a final update to the post. Could you include that final part on the code?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `safe_full_join` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and resolve column conflicts using `dplyr::coalesce` :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)
safe_full_join(dfA, dfB[names(dfA)], by=c("name","surname"), conflict = coalesce, check="") 
#   name surname C
# 1   Ja     Men T
# 2  Ale      Bu T
# 3   Ge     Men T
# 4   Je      Di T
```

`check = ""` is for not displaying warning, as we're joining on factor columns with different levels